# MySql data export to import in sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

This question has been asked a few times.  However the links all lead to how to export the db such as schema and import that into sqlite.  My scenario I already have an sqllite db with the tables.  I need to get the DATA from the mysql db and import it into sqlite3.

I attempt an import into my sqlite3 db using a program.  The error I receive is:

```
Error importing data: Error in statement #1: unrecognized token: "#".
Aborting execution and rolling back.
```

I've researched this error and can't find anything useful.

I've tried dumping my data from mysql and doing one table at a time.  Same error.  My data contains a blob in some tables so a csv export dump won't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Consider using `--hex-blob`.

Comment: I tried that it still gives me the same error.  I select "Output BLOB fields as HEX from a gui program.  @RickJames

Comment: Show us the SQL statement with the naughty `#`.

Comment: That might be part of the problem, I'm using a GUI so when I export I have this: https://screencast.com/t/yDiX2mFAQi .in the actual sql file it has this: https://screencast.com/t/Av25500J . @RickJames

Comment: Give us a) your SQLite table structure in form of **DDL** as **text** - no screenshots from GUIs, then b) a few lines of the data you are inserting (BLOB fields may be truncated!) and c) the statement you are using to import your data. You can edit own question. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: So far I've managed to remove the stuff RickJames hinted at.  What would I do with this: /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `ci_sessions` DISABLE KEYS */;  is this valid in sqlite?  @Vérace

Comment: You might like to look at my MySQLDumpSplitter programme - it takes dumps and splits them into tables - you could Google it with `site:bintray.com`. Might be of use? Disclaimer: I am the author and it's functionality is basic - YMMV!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you dumped from MySQL with `mysqldump`?  And apparently, Sequel PRO does not understand the `#` as a comment character.

(The BLOB is a red herring.)